# Add administration menu item for one role only

Tags: 6, routes, users

I have a module that has configuration pages in the administration side. I want to have one role that's just for administrating that module, but doesn't have any other administrative privileges.

I can give this role access to the path `admin/settings/module/configuration` and they see the form, but since they can't see see the administration menu, they can't navigate to it. They have to paste the URL to it.

I would like to have that path show up as a link in their black admin menu bar at the top. But I don't want it to show up for any other admin, just the Module Administrator role, to keep that bar uncluttered. I can get a custom menu item showing up in the admin bar, but how do I get it to redirect to another page, and how to I stop users without the role from seeing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can get a custom menu item showing up in the admin bar, but how do I get it to redirect to another page, and how to I stop users without the role from seeing it?

You can set the page callback to `drupal_goto`, pass the redirect path and other arguments as `page arguments`, and use the `access arguments` to set permissions.

I love admin menu, but I'm not sure it's something I particularly like putting in the hands of the clients. It's easy to find yourself giving too many perms to the client, and you can't use the menu module to add items to it. I've not used it yet, but on my next project I'm going to try something like [SimpleMenu](http://drupal.org/project/simplemenu).

Comment: Andy thanks for the answer. It's not really a client or website end-user; it's someone on our team who still should not have access to other administrative features.

Comment: Gotcha, hope that helped.